# Width of FrameLayout never truly 0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-framelayout

I'm currently facing a strange bug(?) with ConstraintLayout.
Im trying to set the width of a FrameLayout, which is a child of a Constraintlayout, to 0px.

I set the width via the following code snippet:

```
// set width
val newWidth = 0
val frameParams = frame.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
frameParams.width = newWidth
frame.layoutParams = frameParams
logE("newWidth: $newWidth, frame.measuredWidth: ${frame.measuredWidth}, frame.width: ${frame.width}")
```

Strangely, it seems that my FrameLayout never reaches a "true" width of 0px, but some random values close to 0. See a selection of logs below:

```
E/Log: newWidth: 0, frame.measuredWidth: 6, frame.width: 6
E/Log: newWidth: 0, frame.measuredWidth: 10, frame.width: 10
E/Log: newWidth: 0, frame.measuredWidth: 1, frame.width: 1
```

As you can see, neither the FrameLayouts width, nor its measuredWidth, reach a value of 0.
Is this a known bug, and if so, does anyone know a workaround?

Please let me know if you need any further information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 0dp is "match constraint", if you don't wnat to show it then make it 1px

Comment: @EpicPandaForce That actually did the trick, especially the "1px" hint. Do you mind posting this as an answer, so that it may help others later?

Comment: Typically using View.GONE is the preferred way, except when you're trying to do this in a RecyclerView. There, GONE isn't enough, so using 1px is kind of a hack, but it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s not a bug at all. In constraint layout the `0dp` is evaluated as `match_constraint`, which will take up space based on the constraints you defined.

As stated on the docs:

> The dimension of the widgets can be specified by setting the
>   `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes in **3
>   different ways**:
>
> 1- Using a specific dimension (either a literal value such as 123dp or a
>   Dimension reference);
>
> 2- Using `WRAP_CONTENT`, which will ask the widget to compute its own size;
>
> ***3- Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of `MATCH_CONSTRAINT`***.

If your goal is to make a view disappear, you can change its visibility instead of changing the width or height.

```
val view: View = findViewById(R.id.yourView)
view.visibility = View.GONE // Or View.INVISIBLE
```

Now if you're looking to change the width/height for animation purposes, or for any other reason, change it to 1dp or any other size that fits your needs.

You can read more about `ConstraintLayout` on the [Android training guide](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) and [on its docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).